# Checking if a user is logged in (Strongloop and NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I am using strongloop to create an api that makes use of access tokens.

I have followed this [guide](http://blog.digitopia.com/tokens-sessions-users/) (and also the strongloop docs) to create a cookie that stores the access token and also enables the app to make use of cookies for storing access tokens.

Here is my code for setting the cookie once a user has logged in (common/models/api-user.js):

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Apiuser) {

  // on login set access_token cookie with same ttl as loopback's accessToken
  Apiuser.afterRemote('login', function setLoginCookie(context, accessToken, next) {
      var res = context.res;
      var req = context.req;
      if (accessToken != null) {
          if (accessToken.id != null) {
              res.cookie('access_token', accessToken.id, {
                  signed: req.signedCookies ? true : false,
                  maxAge: accessToken.ttl
              });
              return res.redirect('/');
          }
      }
      return next();
  });

};
```

And then, in my server/server.js , I am using cookie-parser like this to create signed cookies:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var secret = "somesecret";

//use cookie-parser for signed cookies.
app.use(cookieParser(secret));

// use loopback.token middleware on all routes
app.use(loopback.token({
  model: app.models.accessToken,
  currentUserLiteral: 'me',
  searchDefaultTokenKeys: false,
  cookies: ['access_token'],
  headers: ['access_token', 'X-Access-Token'],
  params: ['access_token']
}));
```

After I log in, a cookie is set with name "access_token" , however, it does not seem that loopback uses this cookie / acess token to authenticate requests made to the api.

Furthermore, I have some client side html where I would like to check if a user is logged in by reading the cookie values, however, the access token gets encrypted by using cookie parser and I have no idea how to actually read the access token stored in that cookie client side. I am a bit of a node js noob, so I'd appreciate if anyone can just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a functionality in *ctx* (using accessToken), dont know if you have tried it as 
you have read the docs:

```
app.use(loopback.context());
app.use(loopback.token());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.accessToken) return next();
  app.models.User.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
    res.locals.currentUser = user;
    var loopbackContext = loopback.getCurrentContext();
    if (loopbackContext) loopbackContext.set('currentUser', user);
    next();
  });
});

// anywhere in the app
var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext();
var currentUser = ctx && ctx.get('currentUser');
```

[Current user anywhere or remote methods](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-current-context?src=search.html#use-current-authenticated-user-in-remote-methods)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx = loopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
var accessToken = ctx && ctx.get('accessToken') || null;

if(accessToken && accessToken.userId){
 // it will give you login user's id.
}
```